# Should changing a div's text property via jQuery update the bound ko.observableArray

Tags: knockout.js, foreach, ko.observablearray

I have a container div bound using knockout foreach binding:

```
   <div id="foo" data-bind="foreach: { data: fooObservableArray, afterAdd: afterAdd}">
       <div data-bind="text: $data"></div>
   </div>
```

In the afterAdd method of the ViewModel:

```
     self.fooObservableArray = ko.observableArray([]);

     self.afterAdd = function(element){
           // make some changes to the DIV's text after it has been created
           <snip>
           $(element).text( someNewValue() );
     ;
```

Value `someNewCalculatedValue` is not appearing in  `fooObservableArray` but *is* being displayed in the UI.

Is knockout not observing the div's text property as it would observe the value of a bound input?

What is the proper way to apply an afterAdd modification to the text of the new div element that has been created via the foreach binding?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to be using jQuery to set the text value. Afteradd is a function usually to do some advanced logic, you shouldn't need that.

First change your HTML

```
<div id="foo" data-bind="foreach: fooObservableArray">
    <div data-bind="text: MyText"></div>
</div>
```

Now Update your javascript

```
function MyModel()
{
this.MyText = ko.observable()
}

// Your knockout view model
function ViewModel()
{
 this.fooObservableArray = ko.observableArray();       
} 

var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);

// Create 2 objects
var m1 = new MyModel();
m1.MyText("hello m1");
var m2 = new MyModel();
m2.MyText("hello m2");

// add them to array
vm.fooObservableArray.push(m1);
vm.fooObservableArray.push(m2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't see how to adapt your approach when using knockout's `foreach` binding. Only the markupf or the container exists. The items in the container are created by knockout. Also, there is "advanced logic" involved, or at least "logic". The value of the created div is the result of an ad hoc computation.